# Fingers appear glued to guitar string

Tags: guitar, technique

So, I am playing guitar for around one year now, but I still did not find a solution for the following problem: When I'm lifting up my fingers away from the strings, sometimes they appear as if they are glued to them, thus creating a sound when I do not want to have one. What can I do against this?

Comment: Does this happen on steel strings or nylon?

Comment: Mostly on steel strings

Comment: [This question I asked](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/12292/3032) seems related

Comment: possible duplicate of [String sticking to the fretting finger - how to avoid?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12237/string-sticking-to-the-fretting-finger-how-to-avoid)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three things:

- Make sure you lift directly away from the string. Don't pull the string downwards or push it upwards; this will produce a similar effect to a pull-off.
- Don't lift your finger completely off the string in one go; instead, do what I call a "self-damping-note". Your finger lifts slightly, to let the string lift off the fret, but the finger is still touching the string, and so damps it. Then you should be able to lift (*carefully*) away from the string without it sounding. (This technique does take quite a bit of practice, to ensure that you can execute these two movements quickly and smoothly, and to ensure that you don't lift the string from the fret too slowly, which makes the string buzz against the fret.)
- Lastly, but it really is important, make sure your fingers are clean; if necessary wash your hands before playing. This really does make a difference. If your fingers are a bit sticky, from sweat, dirt, mint-humbugs or whatever, *they will stick to the strings more!*

Comment: Good points, but if he has been playing with dirty fingers, he really should clean the neck and strings too.

Answer (score 1):

Muteeee the strings! Take your right hand (assuming you're right handed) look for the fleshy part on the bottom and rest it gently on the strings. Muting unwanted string noise is one of the most important things when playing with even a little bit of overdrive. Try also muting with your left hand. I'm not in a position to give you a detailed description cause I don't have images to show you how to properly place your hand. Go to YouTube and look up "muting unwanted guitar string noise" there are different techniques. Muting is not only used for unwanted string noise they're sometimes used as a playing dynamic. Example: Metal songs that have that thumping noise guitar or just check out Paul Gilbert he plays really fast while muting gives his sound such a sexy texture. Good luck with your future guitaring endeavors.

Edit:sorry I think I might have written something that's off topic