# Lifting my fingers off the fretboard

Tags: ukulele

Ive been learning uke for about 2 weeks (a long time, I know) but I only bought my first one today. I find that whenever I lift my finger(s) off the fretboard, it makes a noise, like I've strummed. Is there any way to stop this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related question: [String sticking to the fretting finger - how to avoid?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/12237/6851)  Although that question mentions classical guitar, not ukulele, the phenomenon is the same as they both have nylon strings.